# Does convergence of the product of two matrices imply convergence of each matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, matrices, matrix-calculus, matrix-decomposition

I have two sequences of matrices which are not diagonal:
let say $A_n$ is $m\times p$ and $B_n$ is $p\times k$.

I know that the product $A_n B_n$ converges to $AB$,
that is $\Vert A_n B_n - AB\Vert = O( \delta_n)$ with $\delta_n \rightarrow 0$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$
for some norm $\Vert \cdot \Vert$, for example the Froebenuis norm.

I also know that $\Vert A_n \Vert$ and $\Vert B_n \Vert$ are bounded and for identifiability
$A'A= I $.

Is it true that, under some conditions, $\Vert A_n - A\Vert = O(\delta_n) $ and 
$\Vert B_n - B\Vert = O(\delta_n) $? How can I show it?

Comment: Where does come from your condition $AA' =I$ Note that notation $AB$ is confusing because you  don't know if $A$ or $B$ converge when you write the first equality. Denote the limite $C$ and work with it. It will be more clear for you.

Comment: Furthermore you could try Bolzanno Weistrass theorem because your sequences are bounded. It could give you something with $$ ||A_n-A||\leq ||A_{\phi_n}-A_n ||+|| A_{\phi(n)}-A || $$ with $\phi$ the extraction of $A$ resulting of Bolzanno-Weierstrass theorem and $A$ the limit of that extraction. You may furthermore apply that methods on $B$, it may work. But first we really need to know what means $A'A=I$ since $A$ does not exist when you summon it in your post

Comment: I mean that it exists a $m\times p$ matrix $A$ and a $p\times k$ matrix $B$ such that $\Vert A_n B_n - AB\Vert$.
We also impose $A'A= I$ for identifiability.
Indeed, for any $p\times p$ invertible matrices $D$
we have $AB=\tilde{A}\tilde{B}$ where $\tilde A = A D$ and
$\tilde B = D^{-1}B$.
That is why, assuming that $A$ and $A_n$ are orthogonal ($A'A = I$ and $A_n'A_n = I$) solves the identifiability issue.

Comment: However, I know that it is a partial solution since we can restrict $D$ to be orthogonal.
In fact, I would like to know if there is an orthogonal matrix $D$ such that
$\Vert A_n - AD \Vert = O(\delta_n)$.

Comment: Ok I see I will see if I find something

Comment: You notice that $A_n$ is invertible because orthogonal so || B_n-A_n^tAB||||A_n||<o(\delta_n)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will try to answer my own question. For simplicity, I will assume that $B$ and all $B_n$ are orthogonal. Also all matrices are bounded in norm.

The problem is not unique. For example if the matrices $A_n$ and $B_n$ converges,the product can converge to $AB$ but there is no guarantee that $A_n$ converges to $A$ and $B_n$ to $B$.
Indeed, any transformation $A_nD$  and $D^{-1}B_n$ will converge for an invertible $D$: $\lim \Vert A_n D D^{-1} B_n  - AB\Vert =O(\delta_n)$.

So we can reformulated the problem.
Instead, we want to know if there are matrices 
$\tilde A_n= A_n D$ and $\tilde B_n= D^{-1} B_n$ such that 
$\Vert \tilde A_n - A\Vert = O(\delta_n)$ and
$\Vert \tilde B_n - B\Vert = O(\delta_n)$.

Let's take $D$ as the minimizer of 
$\Vert D^{-1} B_n- B \Vert$,
which gives $D=  B_n B'(B B')^{-1} $.
Since $B$ is orthogonal, $D$ should be orthogonal as well and thus
$D= B_n B'$.
We also see that:
$\tilde B_n B' = B B'$.

$\Vert \tilde A_n - A\Vert = \Vert (\tilde A_n - A) B B' \Vert$
$ = \Vert \tilde A_n \tilde B_n B' - AB B'   \Vert
= \Vert \tilde A_n \tilde B_n - AB  \Vert
\Vert B \Vert = O(\delta_n)
$
since $\Vert B \Vert$ is bounded.

For $\tilde B$, we have
$\Vert \tilde B_n - B\Vert 
= \Vert A \tilde B_n - AB  \Vert O(1)
= \Vert \tilde A_n \tilde B_n - A \tilde B_n  \Vert
+ \Vert \tilde A_n \tilde B_n - AB  \Vert O(1)\\ 
=  O(1) \Vert \tilde B_n  \Vert
\Vert \tilde A_n - A  \Vert
+ O(\delta_n) = O(\delta_n)$.